# ipython notebook: How to split large cell output to multiple slides when generating reveal.js slideshow

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, reveal.js

Basically I have a cell which loops through my data and makes various plots.  When I use nbconvert to create a reveal.js slideshow, this cell and its output is made as a single long slide that vertically scrolls to show all plots.

I noticed on the nbconvert github issues page some discussion on this topic but I did not see any alternative solutions offered.

Ideally I would like to be able to split this set of plot outputs into individual slides, any idea's on how this can be done or if it is supported?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This start to be on the limit of what nbconvert does and might require some work.
Basically you will have to understand `IPython/nbconvert/templates/skeleton/null.tpl`. No need to change the file itself as you can redefine it and give nbconvert other path to search for it if you need more logic. You will have to make a template that overwrite the right blocks In particular you are interested in this section that loops through each output.

```
{%- block output_group -%}
     {%- block output_prompt -%}{%- endblock output_prompt -%}
          {%- block outputs scoped -%}
                {%- for output in cell.outputs -%}
                .... some stuff
 ... closing blocks
```

Second problem is that the metadata does not support asking where to split output. But I guess you can probably always make a new output on a new slide on your case. As for "is it supported" the answer will be that you can overwrite almost everything you like, but we try to keep a bare minimum in IPython itself.

I know the doc is missing on that and we'll try to fix that up. If you're ready to hack for a day or two I think what you ask is doable, but will need some deep diving into how nbconvert works.

Note that there is a [IPython wiki page](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/Cookbook%3a%20nbconvert%20templates) where we should put example of custom templates that hasn't be filled yet.

Comment: this seems an interesting feature to have, just wonder if there are any updates on this? Thanks